# Scheme: Passing '+' and '0' as arguments

Tags: scheme, racket

This may be a very noob question but I am new to Scheme. When I try the following command:

```
(equal? (((lambda (s z) (s 3 z)) + 0) 3))
```

It gives me following error:

```
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: 3
  arguments...:
```

The way I understand, the expression should evaluate to (+ 3 0) which is equal to 3. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One paranthesis pair too much.

I recommend you to use automatic indentation in DrRacket for each argument in such more complicated expressions.

This is the correct version:

```
(equal? ((lambda (s z) (s 3 z)) + 0)
        3)
;; #t
```

Note, the `3)` is exactly aligned to the `((lambda ...`, indicating it is at exactly the same level with the lambda-expression containing s-expression.

See what would have happened, if you would have started new line in DrRacket with the previous code, to specify and test that `3` is the second argument to `equal?`:

```
(equal? (((lambda (s z) (s 3 z)) + 0)
         3))
```

Do you see? The `3` is off by one position. It is not exactly aligned to the beginning of `(((lambda ...`. But you would know, it should, if 3 and the lambda expression-bearing s-expression are at the same hierarchy level (like being arguments to the function `equal?`).

That is why lispers swear by automatic-indentation-capable lisp editors. Because through such small, but important, hints the automatic indentation helps you to tame the parantheses.